# Unable to start XAMPP Apache Server

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost, server

I want to start a Apache Server on my Windows Server using Remote Desktop.

Here is what I did. Since I don't want to use my server's port 80 or 443:

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
Listen 8080
```

Apache server is not starting.

No error logs are printed in apache error log file.

Port 8080 is not used by any application, checked Netstat, No Skype.

**Solution please?**

Comment: what is your apache log? you can get that info from the xampp output.

Comment: Have you tried a different port? if so, does it work ?

Comment: Where is the XAMPP-folder located?

Comment: change 8080 from httpd-ssl.conf and try 443 and restart apache

Comment: XAMPP folder is in D: drive, tried 8012(free port), 8000. Apache log file is empty since I just installed XAMPP

Comment: 80 and 443 are prohibited (blocked already)

Comment: Did you start XAMPP with administrator rights?

Comment: Tried already to Run as Admin, no luck!

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED: Chrome gives me this error!

Answer (score 0):

you just have to check your IIS if IIS is installed then uninstall it....

Comment: I have a paid windows server that I am using. IIS is already installed. I cannot uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

Change apache's port settings to 81 and apache will work.

Comment: Not happening @Shubham Sahu